# Problem passing decimal value to database (Access)

Tags: c#, ms-access, decimal

I want to pass decimal value to database table. When I send value 1,5 to database then save value as 15.

```
Code:

txtKm.Text="1,5";
zelezniceDataSet.VozniRediRow row;
row.Km = decimal.Parse(txtKm.Text);

zelezniceDataSet.VozniRedi.AddVozniRediRow(row);
vozniRediTableAdapter.Update(zelezniceDataSet.VozniRedi);
```

When debug decimal parsing the value is correct (1.5)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at an [overloaded form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx) of decimal.Parse that accepts a culture-specific format option. My guess is decimal.Parse sees your comma as a thousands-separator and just removes it.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that `decimal.Parse` is ignoring the comma ... if you pass "1.5" is the correct value saved? If so then you need to use the overload that takes the culture to use when parsing `Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles)` and pass it the correct number style for the language you are using.

EDIT ... more info ..

```
decimal.Parse(test, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-us").NumberFormat );
```

will output 15 for test = "1,5" because in English the "," char is the thousands separator

```
decimal.Parse(test, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-nl").NumberFormat );
```

will output 1.5 for test = "1,5" because in Dutch the "," char is the decimal separator

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if pass "1.5" then it's the same (15)

Comment: If the value parsed is correct when you breakpoint on it then it has to be something in the call to save to the db. Is your column set to decimal type? Does row.Km contain the correct value after the parse?

Comment: Yes, column is set to decimal type. row.Km also contain the correct value.